# SPARQL select query with condition?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, ontology, virtuoso

I'm trying to form SPARQL query which will give Domain Names and Method Name against the given Java Class from below RDF. For e.g

Select DomainNames, MethodName where JavaClass = 'MyJavaClass'. 
This is just a pseudo query. I need help in forming similar query in SPARQL. thanks.

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:DOL="http://www.MyOnt.com/something/v1#"
    xmlns:DC="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/"
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyJavaClass">
    <DOL:belongsTo>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyDomain">
        <DOL:domainName>MyDomainValue2</DOL:domainName>
        <DOL:domainName>MyDomainValue</DOL:domainName>
      </rdf:Description>
    </DOL:belongsTo>
    <DOL:hasMethod>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyMethod">
        <DOL:returnType>MethodReturnType</DOL:returnType>
      </rdf:Description>
    </DOL:hasMethod>
    <foaf:name>MyJavaClass</foaf:name>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's generally easier to understand what the SPARQL query should look like if you first put the data into Turtle, which has a syntax very similar to SPARQL.  Here's what your data is in Turtle:

```
@prefix DOL:   <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/v1#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix DC:    <http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/> .

<http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyDomain>
        DOL:domainName  "MyDomainValue2" , "MyDomainValue" .

<http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyJavaClass>
        DOL:belongsTo  <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyDomain> ;
        DOL:hasMethod  <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyMethod> ;
        foaf:name      "MyJavaClass" .

<http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyMethod>
        DOL:returnType  "MethodReturnType" .
```

Once you've done that, the query looks almost exactly like the data, except with variables in it.  The only catch here is that since you're looking for domains and methods, you need to use a **union** (assuming that you want to bind domains and methods as different variables).

```sql
prefix DOL:   <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/v1#>
prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

select ?domain ?method {
  ?class foaf:name "MyJavaClass" .
  { ?class DOL:belongsTo ?domain }
  union
  { ?class DOL:hasMethod ?method }
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| domain                                         | method                                         |
===================================================================================================
| <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyDomain> |                                                |
|                                                | <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyMethod> |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you're willing to have the domain and method bound to the same variable, you can use an alternation property path to select *either* a domain or a method:

```sql
prefix DOL:   <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/v1#>
prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

select ?domainOrMethod {
  ?class foaf:name "MyJavaClass" ;
         DOL:belongsTo|DOL:hasMethod ?domainOrMethod 
}
```

```
--------------------------------------------------
| domainOrMethod                                 |
==================================================
| <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyDomain> |
| <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyMethod> |
--------------------------------------------------
```

As another alternative, you could use a **values** block to specify the properties that you want to follow (**hasMethod** or **belongsTo**), in which case you can select that as well in order to know which type of value you have:

```sql
prefix DOL:   <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/v1#>
prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

select ?property ?value {
  values ?property { DOL:belongsTo DOL:hasMethod }
  ?class foaf:name "MyJavaClass" ;
         ?property ?value  
}
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| property      | value                                          |
==================================================================
| DOL:belongsTo | <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyDomain> |
| DOL:hasMethod | <http://www.MyOnt.com/something/data/MyMethod> |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The problem that I see is mostly that many people here do not try to learn or understand at least some SPARQL basics first. It's much effort and great work from your side, but I don't think that the next query can be written by themselves.

Comment: @Joshua: Thanks for your detailed explanation. It helped a lot indeed. My objective was to display domain values as well as return type. I've modified your query and getting the desired results. In fact, I kept your query same and added two more variables "dValues" and "rType". It works fine, but I just don't understand that I've to use different variable for both of above mentioned variable: here is one of the code snippet: 
`{ ?class2 DOL:domainName ?dValues }`
It works when I use "class2" but do not work with "class". It looks like "class" is already defined and this getting conflict?